# Vue транзакция не работает

Tags: vue.js, анимация, css-animation

Анимация не работает. Добавление параметра key="test" не работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Начнем с того, что код нужно прикладывать текстом, а не картинками.

Comment: А что вообще работает? Какой результат?

Comment: Наработает от слова совсем.